# Accessing Method that is not included in Constructor

Tags: java, mysql

I have a class that I created to connect to a database and do various inserts, delete, alter etc...

An array is included to show all. In the database an ID is created automatically so I do not input it, but I would still like the array to output the ID from each column. The code I have is seen below and if I insert cID before cJourneys etc.I get the constructor is undefined. Looking to figure out how to access the ID from the database to call it each time with the array..

```
public Car(String cLicenseIn, int cJourneysIn, String cUsernameIn, String cPasswordIn) {
    cLicense = cLicenseIn;
    cJourneys = cJourneysIn;
    cUsername = cUsernameIn;
    cPassword = cPasswordIn;
```

}

```
// Display all Vehicles
public ArrayList<Car> getAllCar() {
    ArrayList<Car> AllCar = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from eflow.Registration");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Car nextCar = new Car(resultSet.getString("cLicense"), resultSet.getInt("cJourneys"),
                    resultSet.getString("cUsername"), resultSet.getString("cPassword").toString());
            AllCar.add(nextCar);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return AllCar;
}
```

Comment: How about adding another constructor that also takes an ID? Also, what is the point of `getString("cPassword").toString()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner OP is saying that if a 5th `resultSet.getInt("cID")` call is added to the `new Car` statement between `cLicense` and `cJourneys` (*"if I insert cID before cJourneys"*), it's complaining that there is no 5-parameter constructor on `Car`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Like methods, constructors can also be overloaded (accepting different set of arguments)** in Java, so you can overload the `Car` constructor which accepts id as well i.e., you will be having two constructors for your `Car` class.

**`Car` constructor with id parameter (use this whenever you want to Create `Car` from database):**

```
public Car(String id, String cLicenseIn, 
 int cJourneysIn, String cUsernameIn, String cPasswordIn) {
  //set fields here
}
```

**`Car` constructor without id parameter (use this whenever you want to create `Car` from user inputs):**

```
public Car(String cLicenseIn, int cJourneysIn, 
             String cUsernameIn, String cPasswordIn) {
   //set fields here
}
```

**getAllCar() method:**

```
public ArrayList<Car> getAllCar() {
    ArrayList<Car> AllCar = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
           //add your existing code here

            Car nextCar = new Car(resultSet.getString("ID"), ,
               resultSet.getString("cLicense"), 
               resultSet.getInt("cJourneys"),
               resultSet.getString("cUsername"),
               resultSet.getString("cPassword").toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       //add null checks and close the resources
       statement.close();
       conn.close();
       resultSet.close();
    }
    return AllCar;
}
```

Also, **I strongly suggest you to close the resources in the `finally` block or use `try` with resources, otherwise you will end up with resource leaks**.

Comment: Do I just need to create a 2nd constructor and I should be able to add the ID to the array?